# Python Selenium Pressing Button

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Selenium to try and press this button, but Selenium complains that it does not exists

```
<button name="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="show-when-enabled"><svg class="bi flex-shrink-0 me-2" height="24" role="img" width="24"><use href="#icon_content-save"></use></svg><span class="pe-3">Save Database/Server</span></span><span class="show-when-disabled"><span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"></span><span class="px-3">Please wait, saving record...</span></span></button>
```

Here is the first command

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type=submit]").click()
```

This is the second

```
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Save Database/Server").click()
```

and the third command

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[.//span[text()='Save Database/Server']]").click()
```

All three error because Selenium says it does not exists. How should I press the submit button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `xpath` and css selector seems wrong. there is no `anchor` tag.

It should have been.
XPATH:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[.//span[text()='Save Database/Server']]").click()
```

Css Selector:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button[type='submit']").click()
```

`LINK_TEXT` supports only for `anchor` tag not `button` tag.

Comment: For what ever reason the second line of code Css Selector failed. with Error : "ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=99.0.1150.39)
Stacktrace:"

Comment: The first line xpath worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using wait and action if not use the below.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("yourxPath").click()


WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "YourXpath"))).click()


time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("YourXpath")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)


time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("Xpath")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

Comment: Yes there are waits. This is form I have filled 5 fields with no issue. The last thing I am doing is trying to run submit. I have also tried to run as individual statement once page is fully loaded and still fails.  Thank you Akzy.

Answer (score 0):

Try it may be work

`driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)`

And can you write down the mistake you made?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).